# How to repeat-x background of a image in fabric when rezise it

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

I want to repeat background when i resize it.

Here is my code, i've tried.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
  clipTo: function(ctx) {
    ctx.rect(1000, 1000, 400, 400);
  }
});
fabric.Image.fromURL('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAAAyCAIAAACRXR/mAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAASdEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAEdyZWVuc2hvdF5VCAUAAADLSURBVFhH7ZnBCoMwEET9/68URBHSNj0UolFoI+aQickKlT05jz0MGQIPkb2kadu3ta42ff/MTtLRazct55bajOMjO0lHr920vnWMMTGV0GuphVALoRaiqNV1dq4TLsdUIrTe+z0fw+ndmEo0w/D61AmXYyqh1179WjGVuNLyl0eohVALuZ8Wtzwgt9zyiNxSC6EWQi1EUYtbHpBbbnlEbqmFUAuhFqKoxS0PyC23PCK31EKohVAL0dXK3vLSOX0TnKZ1z8fw/3uiW37L27QIZwrV4gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==', function(img) {
  var patternSourceCanvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas();
  patternSourceCanvas.add(img);
  var pattern = new fabric.Pattern({
    source: function() {
      patternSourceCanvas.setDimensions({
        width: img.getWidth(),
        height: img.getHeight()
      });
      return patternSourceCanvas.getElement();
    },
    repeat: 'repeat'
  });
  var rectangle = new fabric.Rect({
    fill: pattern,
    left: 1150,
    top: 1150,
    width: img.getWidth(),
    height: img.getHeight()
  });
  canvas.add(rectangle);
  canvas.renderAll();
});

canvas.on('object:scaling', function(e) {
  if (e.target != null) {
    console.log(e.target);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  top: -1000px;
  left: -1000px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.17/fabric.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <canvas id="c" width="2400" height="2400"></canvas>
</div>
```

How can I make, background repeat?

Here is [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hoa_truong/86t2b8bs/23/)

Comment: Please help me repeat background of a image when i resize it code here : https://jsfiddle.net/hoa_truong/86t2b8bs/23/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=86t2b8bs

Comment: Add the code in the question, tabing it with 4 spaces and add the link.

Comment: @NgọcHòa It is better to include your code in the question, not as external link to jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

@Ngọc Hòa we'll have to use `object:scaling` event to scale the object back to 1x and change size of the object to make repeat the pattern instead of scaling it. See it here

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
fabric.Object.prototype.transparentCorners = false;

  var padding = 0;

  fabric.Image.fromURL('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAAAyCAIAAACRXR/mAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAASdEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAEdyZWVuc2hvdF5VCAUAAADLSURBVFhH7ZnBCoMwEET9/68URBHSNj0UolFoI+aQickKlT05jz0MGQIPkb2kadu3ta42ff/MTtLRazct55bajOMjO0lHr920vnWMMTGV0GuphVALoRaiqNV1dq4TLsdUIrTe+z0fw+ndmEo0w/D61AmXYyqh1179WjGVuNLyl0eohVALuZ8Wtzwgt9zyiNxSC6EWQi1EUYtbHpBbbnlEbqmFUAuhFqKoxS0PyC23PCK31EKohVAL0dXK3vLSOX0TnKZ1z8fw/3uiW37L27QIZwrV4gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==', function(img) {

    img.scaleToWidth(50);
    var patternSourceCanvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas();
    patternSourceCanvas.add(img);
    patternSourceCanvas.renderAll();
    var pattern = new fabric.Pattern({
      source: function() {
        patternSourceCanvas.setDimensions({
          width: img.getScaledWidth() + padding,
          height: img.getScaledHeight() + padding
        });
        patternSourceCanvas.renderAll();
        return patternSourceCanvas.getElement();
      },
      repeat: 'repeat'
    }); 

    var rect = new fabric.Rect({
        width: 250,
        height: 250,
        fill: pattern,
        objectCaching: false
    });

    canvas.add(rect);
    rect.center().setCoords();

 });



canvas.on('object:scaling', function(e) {
  if (e.target != null) {
    console.log(e.target);
    var obj = e.target;
        var height = obj.height * obj.scaleY;
        var width = obj.width * obj.scaleX;
        obj.height = height;
        obj.width = width;
        obj.scaleX = 1;
        obj.scaleY = 1;
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dotriz/ajsdmg4s/

Comment: Thank Riz so much :)